# I would like to remove a part of my text that is produced

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I have code that looks like this:

```
page %>% 
  html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.imdb.com", ., 
             "fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl", sep = "")
```

and produced this as an outcome for example:
"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=adv_li_ttfullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
I would like to get rid of the "?ref_=adv_li_tt" part of each outcome. Is there a specific function in dplyr that can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the url you are using to get `page` ?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to get the cast names, but it is a link within a link within a link and I am struggling with that part. I have gotten to the point where I have produced the outcome mentioned above, but I need to remove one part of it.

Comment: Please respect IMDB's conditions: https://www.imdb.com/conditions "Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below. " Please see https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/ on how to scrape their data in the way they intend you to.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you for bringing it up!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything from the `?` to the end of the url with `str_remove("\\?.*")`. Adding this line allows your code to return all 100 valid urls on the page.

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

page <- read_html(paste0("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?count=100&",
                         "groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating"))

page %>% 
  html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  str_remove("\\?.*") %>%
  paste("https://www.imdb.com", ., "fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl", sep = "") 
#>   [1] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [2] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [3] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [4] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167260/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [5] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108052/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [6] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071562/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [7] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050083/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>   [8] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15097216/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>   [9] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10698680/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>  [10] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [11] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6710474/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [12] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [13] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167261/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [14] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137523/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [15] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [16] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [17] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060196/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [18] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10189514/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>  [19] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0133093/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [20] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [21] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080684/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [22] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073486/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [23] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [24] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317248/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [25] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245429/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [26] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120815/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [27] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120689/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [28] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118799/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [29] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114369/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [30] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [31] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102926/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [32] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [33] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056058/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [34] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047478/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [35] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [36] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9477520/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [37] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6751668/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [38] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2582802/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [39] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1675434/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [40] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10280296/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>  [41] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0482571/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [42] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [43] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0253474/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [44] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0172495/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [45] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120586/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [46] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114814/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [47] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110413/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [48] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110357/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [49] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095765/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [50] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095327/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [51] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [52] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078788/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [53] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [54] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064116/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [55] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054215/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [56] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047396/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [57] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [58] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027977/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [59] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0021749/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [60] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8503618/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [61] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8267604/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [62] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8178634/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [63] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7286456/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [64] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7019842/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [65] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5311514/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [66] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4633694/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [67] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [68] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [69] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2380307/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [70] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1853728/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [71] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [72] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12361178/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>  [73] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1187043/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [74] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10872600/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>  [75] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10295212/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
#>  [76] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [77] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405094/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [78] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364569/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [79] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209144/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [80] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169547/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [81] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119698/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [82] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112573/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [83] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091251/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [84] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [85] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086879/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [86] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082971/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [87] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082096/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [88] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081505/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [89] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057565/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [90] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057012/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [91] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051201/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [92] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050825/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [93] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043014/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [94] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032553/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [95] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7060344/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [96] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6316138/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [97] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5074352/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [98] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3417422/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#>  [99] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2106476/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" 
#> [100] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1832382/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. That is a huge help